# How to use one print() in python to print list items line by line - not in one streak?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`mister` is a list of lists. `print(mister)` gives this in the Python shell:

```
[['ququ.kz', 1], ['gp.kz', 1], ['gmail.ru', 1], ['mail.ru', 1], ['tlc.com', 1], ['mail.ko', 1], ['microsoft.jp', 1], ['hotmail.eu', 1], ['soman.com', 1], ['swedenborgen.sn', 1], ['customergoogle.com', 1], ['mail.jp', 2], ['gmail.com', 3], ['mail.ru', 3], ['hotmail.com', 3], ['mail.jp', 3], ['mail.com', 4], ['hotmail.com', 4], ['gmail.com', 4], ['mail.kz', 5], ['mail.cn', 7], ['hotmail.com', 9], ['customers.kz', 9], ['microsoft.com', 10], ['conestogamall.com', 13]]
```

Can I use `print()` one time and get nice output - line by line, instead of one big streak?
Or is the only solution:

```
for email_date_entry in mister:
    print(email_date_entry)
```

Is there another elegant way to use **only one `print` call**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass your list as *separate* arguments to `print()` using the `*` variable argument syntax:

```
print(*mister, sep='\n')
```

Now each element in `mister` is seen as a separate argument, and is printed with a `\n` separator:

```
>>> mister = [['ququ.kz', 1], ['gp.kz', 1], ['gmail.ru', 1], ['mail.ru', 1], ['tlc.com', 1], ['mail.ko', 1], ['microsoft.jp', 1], ['hotmail.eu', 1], ['soman.com', 1], ['swedenborgen.sn', 1], ['customergoogle.com', 1], ['mail.jp', 2], ['gmail.com', 3], ['mail.ru', 3], ['hotmail.com', 3], ['mail.jp', 3], ['mail.com', 4], ['hotmail.com', 4], ['gmail.com', 4], ['mail.kz', 5], ['mail.cn', 7], ['hotmail.com', 9], ['customers.kz', 9], ['microsoft.com', 10], ['conestogamall.com', 13]]
>>> print(*mister, sep='\n')
['ququ.kz', 1]
['gp.kz', 1]
['gmail.ru', 1]
['mail.ru', 1]
['tlc.com', 1]
['mail.ko', 1]
['microsoft.jp', 1]
['hotmail.eu', 1]
['soman.com', 1]
['swedenborgen.sn', 1]
['customergoogle.com', 1]
['mail.jp', 2]
['gmail.com', 3]
['mail.ru', 3]
['hotmail.com', 3]
['mail.jp', 3]
['mail.com', 4]
['hotmail.com', 4]
['gmail.com', 4]
['mail.kz', 5]
['mail.cn', 7]
['hotmail.com', 9]
['customers.kz', 9]
['microsoft.com', 10]
['conestogamall.com', 13]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `pprint` (Pretty Print) from `pprint` module - it works for almost every type and usually gives nice output. Usage:

```
from pprint import pprint
...
pprint(mister)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit based on @jonrsharpe's suggestion**

Try this:

```
print('\n'.join(map(str, mister)))
```

What this code does:

- Converts to string every item in the list.
- Joins all obtained strings by a line break separator.
- Prints the result.

This approach works for both Python2.x and Python3.x.

Comment: You can also use `'\n'.join(list(map(str, mister)))` - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/3001761) for why you should pass a list to `str.join`.

Comment: Great tip! The best part of answering questions in Stack Overflow is getting others to improve your answers. :) Thanks!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: here, the `list()` call is redundant; `str.join()` will call it for you anyway.